# Fast search for a set of elements

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, .net-4.0, io

I am trying to search a bunch of files on my hard drive for a binary pattern. I have tried to find some way of doing it with what is built in to .net but I can't seem to find anything that would let me search for a set of data, instead of just one byte of data, unless I convert my binary data in to a string first and use `String.IndexOf(string value)`.

I am halfway through writing my own Boyer-Moor stream searching algorithm, but I thought I should check here first in case I did miss a way to do this efficiently.

Here is my current method of doing the search just for text, it works well enough, I just don't know what to do for binary patterns

```
private string _string;
private byte[] _array;

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(Directory.EnumerateFiles(_folder, _filter, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        , Search);
}

private void Search(string filePath)
{

    if (numbers)
    {
        var fileBinary = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        if (fileBinary.MagicFunctionToDoContains(_array)) //Need help here
        {
            lbResults.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(AddResult), filePath);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var fileText = File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.ASCII);
        if (fileText.IndexOf(_string, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            lbResults.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(AddResult), filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

The byte arrays will not be bigger than 8 bytes at the very largest, with the common case being 4 bytes, if that affects the recommendation.

Is there any thing built in to .net or pre-written example that I could use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding the Boyer-Moor algorithm should be straightforward. However, for such short patterns (4-8 bytes) I doubt you see much performance boost compared to to a byte by byte search.

What you can do to increase performance, is to use pointer arithmetic using the `unsafe` and `fixed` keywords, since the array indexer will bounds check your index variable each time you access your *fileBinary* array.

Comment: Also are there any built in functions to do a  "byte by byte" comparison of two arrays other than [Enumerable.SeqenceEqual(TSource)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to search the files as they are on the disk, or do you want to build an index and later search using that index?

- If the former is the case, I don't see a reason why Boyer–Moore couldn't be implemented on byte "characters".
- If the later is the case, you'll need a specialized data structure such as suffix tree.

BTW, loading the content of the whole file might not be the best idea performance wise - what if you happen to run into a multi-GB video file? Since all you are doing is linearly traversing the file content, you can load it chunk-by-chunk.

For a really performant implementation, separate the search and the chunk-loading into concurrent threads (or better yet, TPL `Task`s) with the queue (of chunks) in between. There may even be some benefits in reading multiple files in parallel to utilize the *native command queuing* implemented in most modern disk controllers (but only for mechanical disks, SSDs don't benefit from NCQ).

Comment: They could even use Memory Mapped files to help partition out the work of large files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything in the .Net Framework that will do what you are trying to accomplish using byte[]. But I think a simple solution would be to convert each byte to char and then the char[] to a string; so you would convert the filedata to char[] and then string and also the data you are searching for and then use the string search algorithms build into .Net. It would save the time of having to roll your own pattern searching algorithm, plus if the data is not large overhead should be negligible.

Comment: Arbitrary binary data can hardly be parsed into a string. Strings must follow the Unicode convention, certain values are illegal. Also, comparisons behave differently.